# Beware of unusual characters!

Tags: feature-request, bug, help-center

Stack Overflow's markdown help documentation, in the [Bare URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#bare-urls) section, tells us to

> beware of unusual characters in your URLs

without specifying what "unusual characters" are. They are not defined in [RFC 1738 - Uniform Resource Locators (URL)](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt).

One of the banes of being a programmer is incomplete documentation.

Please edit the documentation to explicitly state what the unusual characters are.

Comment: Comments explaining why incomplete documentation is a good thing are acceptable.

Comment: Just a basic disclaimer, they could not practically test all possible combinations of unusual Unicode codepoints.   You'll know it when you see it.

Comment: Perhaps an [IDN homograph attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDN_homograph_attack).